# After installing 15.04 Unity does not load. How do I fix this?

Tags: unity, system-installation

Just installed Ubuntu 15.04, coming from Windows 7, and after installing then restarting the computer, I log in to my account and am presented with just the default background. Unity does not load and I have no desktop/launcher. I am unable to do ANYTHING

Have I missed something during installation?